# Page can't hand request - HTTP ERROR 500 - when updating something

Tags: admin, errors, http

I have a wordpress website filled with lots of different content (news, posts, products in an online shop, etc.). I had some problems with the famous "Internal Server Error 500" yesterday, but after contacting my hosting provider they used a restore point from 5 days ago and the error was gone.

But now, everytime a try to update or add an article, product, whatever, i always get the following: "This page is not working. (mysite) can't handle the request right now. HTTP ERROR 500

Do you guys have any idea what it might be? I'm freaking out!

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP ERROR 500` either with your `apache server` or there's something wrong with your `php codes`.

My guess is a wordpress plugin or two is not compatible with the upgrades. Making one or more incompatibility is bad news to php.

Do this:

1. Go access your site's files via SFTP. It could be file zilla or your favorite FTP client. If you don't know how to do that, just go to `Cpanel > File Manager`
2. Locate `public_html/wp-content` and rename the folder from `plugins` to anything you wanted. This will disable the plugin. Please take note that you can reactivate the plugin/s at the `wordpress > plugins`
3. Go access your site on your browser. If it's fine then login to your wordpress admin and reactivate the plugins one by one and test if it's working. If your site shows the error after a certain plugin has been deactivated, then the problem's with the plugin.